# keep $stateparams parameters values after refresh the browser

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788230/how-to-keep-stateparams-parameters-after-i-refresh-the-browser) about how to keep $stateparams parameters values after refresh the browser. but I didn't want to show my params in URL.

I remove the param from URL, but after refresh the browser miss params values.

check also this example :
http://embed.plnkr.co/inFhDmP42AQyeUBmyIVl/

can any one to help me?

Comment: Please put all of the important information into the question; links to external sites can fail, and that leaves your question useless for future readers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store somewhere those values. So, if you don't want them in the url, then you can use `$localStorage` or `$sessionStorage`.